# Try except works when file is run from IDE but when compiled into exe with pyinstaller it doesnt work

Tags: python

I created a python tool with Tkinter GUI. These are the pieces of the script. The problem is with the try-except in these lines of code.

```
try:
   pldf_csv[data['sls_data']['add_columns']].write_csv(endpath,sep='\t')
except:
   write_eror_status = True
   print("CANNOT WRITE FILE")
```

If I run the python file via VSCode the try-except works like this

[image]

But then if I compile the script with `pyinstaller` to `exe`, those line doesn't execute at all

Full code

```
class IngestGenerator:
    def __init__(self, fn,fd,n3pl):
        self.filename = fn
        self.filedir = fd
        self.name3pl = n3pl
    
    def generate_result_csv(self):
        """To extend 3PL please refer to comment with <(extend this)> note
           Don't forget to extend the yaml when extending 3PL
        """
        
        start_time = time.time()

        # with open("columns 1a.yaml", 'r') as f:
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'columns 1a.yaml'), 'r') as f:
            data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
            try :
                # create new list if there's new 3pl behavior (extend this)
                list_type_like = [data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['name3pl'] for i in range(0,len(data['behavior']['type_like']))] #collects names of 3pl which have categorical column to be divided based on
                write_eror_status = False
                status = False
                for i in range(0,len(data['behavior']['type_like'])):
                    if data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['name3pl']==self.name3pl: #get the name of category column and the values of categories (extend this whole if-statement)
                        list_types = data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['cats']
                        cat_column = data['behavior']['type_like'][i]['categorical_col']
                        status = True
                    else : pass
                if status == False: #for logging to check if its in the list of type-like 3pl (extend this whole if else statement)
                    print("3PL cannot be found on type-like 3PL list")
                else: print("3PL can be found on type-like 3PL list")

                try:
                    for cat in list_types: #dynamic list creation for each category (extend this line only)
                        globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"] = []
                except : print("3pl isn't split based on it's categories")

                xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
                print("Cast to CSV first (win32com)")
                wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(self.filename,ReadOnly=1)
                xl.DisplayAlerts = False
                xl.Visible = False
                xl.ScreenUpdating = False
                xl.EnableEvents = False
                sheet_names = [sheet.Name for sheet in wb.Sheets if sheet.Name.lower() != 'summary']
                print("Sheet names")
                print(sheet_names)

                for sheet_name in sheet_names:
                    print("Reading sheet "+sheet_name)
                    ws = wb.Worksheets(sheet_name)
                    ws.SaveAs(tmpdirname+"\\myfile_tmp_{}.csv".format(sheet_name), 24)

                    used_columns = data['sls_data'][f'{self.name3pl.lower()}_used_columns']
                    renamed_columns = data['sls_data'][f'{self.name3pl.lower()}_rename_columns']
                    rowskip = data['behavior']['row_skip'][f'{self.name3pl.lower()}']
                    list_dtypes = [str for u in used_columns]
                    print("CP 1")

                    scandf = pl.scan_csv(tmpdirname+"\\myfile_tmp_{}.csv".format(sheet_name),skip_rows= rowskip,n_rows=10) #scan csv to get column name
                    print(scandf.columns)
                    scanned_cols = scandf.columns.copy()
                    used_cols_inDF = [] #collects column names dynamically
                    for i in range(0,len(used_columns)):
                        if type(used_columns[i]) is list: #check for each scanned-columns which contained in yaml used_columns, append if the scanned columns exist in yaml
                            for sc in scanned_cols:
                                for uc in used_columns[i]:
                                    if sc == uc:
                                        print(f"Column match : {uc}")
                                        used_cols_inDF.append(uc)
                                    else:pass       
                        else:
                            for sc in scanned_cols: #purpose is same with the if statement
                                if sc == used_columns[i]:
                                    print(f"Column match : {used_columns[i]}")
                                    used_cols_inDF.append(used_columns[i])
                                else:pass
                    print(used_cols_inDF)
                    """
                    JNT files have everchanging column names. Some files only have Total Ongkir, some only have Total,
                    and some might have Total and Total Ongkir. If both exists then will use column Total Ongkir (extend this if necessary i.e for special cases of 3pl)
                    """
                    if self.name3pl == 'JNT':
                        if "Total" in used_cols_inDF and "Total Ongkir" in used_cols_inDF:
                            used_cols_inDF.remove("Total")
                        else:pass
                    else:pass 
                    
                    pldf_csv = pl.read_csv(tmpdirname+"\\myfile_tmp_{}.csv".format(sheet_name),
                            columns = used_cols_inDF,
                            new_columns = renamed_columns,
                            dtypes = list_dtypes,
                            skip_rows= rowskip
                        ).filter(~pl.fold(acc=True, f=lambda acc, s: acc & s.is_null(), exprs=pl.all(),)) #filter rows with all null values
                    print(pldf_csv)
                    print(pldf_csv.columns)
                    
                    for v in data['sls_data']['add_columns']: #create dynamic columns
                        if "3pl invoice distance (m) (optional)" in v.lower() or "3pl cod amount (optional)" in v.lower():
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column(pl.Series(name="{}".format(v),values= np.zeros(shape=pldf_csv.shape[0])))
                        elif "3pl tn (mandatory)" in v.lower() or  "weight (kg) (optional)" in v.lower():
                            pass
                        elif "total fee (3pl) (optional)" in v.lower():
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column(pl.col(v).str.replace_all(",","").str.strip().cast(pl.Float64,False).fill_null(0))
                        else : 
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column(pl.lit(None).alias(v))
                    print(pldf_csv)
                    
                    endpath = self.filedir+"\{}_{}_{}.csv".format(get_file_name(file_name_appear_label["text"]),sheet_name,"IngestResult").replace('/','\\')
                    if self.name3pl not in list_type_like: #(extend this line only)
                        if self.name3pl == 'JNT': #(extend this line and its statement if necessary i.e for special cases of 3pl)
                            pldf_csv = pldf_csv.with_column((pl.col("Total Fee (3PL) (Optional)")+pl.col("Biaya Asuransi").str.replace_all(",","").str.strip().cast(pl.Float64,False).fill_null(0)).alias("Total Fee (3PL) (Optional)"))
                        else: pass
                        print(pldf_csv)
                        try:
                            pldf_csv[data['sls_data']['add_columns']].write_csv(endpath,sep='\t')
                        except:
                            write_eror_status = True
                            print("CANNOT WRITE FILE")
                    elif self.name3pl in list_type_like: #(extend this line only)
                        for cat in list_types:
                            globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"].append(pldf_csv.filter(pl.col(cat_column).str.contains(cat)))

                if self.name3pl not in list_type_like:
                    pass
                elif self.name3pl in list_type_like:
                    for cat in list_types:
                            globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"] = pl.concat(globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"])
                            print(globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"])
                            globals()[f"endpath_{cat}"] = self.filedir+"\{}_{}_{}.csv".format(get_file_name(file_name_appear_label["text"]),cat,"IngestResult").replace('/','\\')
                            print("done creating paths")
                            try:
                                globals()[f"{cat}_final_df"][data['sls_data']['add_columns']].write_csv(globals()[f"endpath_{cat}"],sep='\t')
                            except :
                                write_eror_status = True
                                print("CANNOT WRITE FILE")
                if write_eror_status == False:
                    progress_label["text"] = "Successful!"
                else:
                    progress_label["text"] = "Cannot write result into Excel, please close related Excel files and kill Excel processes from Task Manager"

                print("Process finished")
            except Exception as e:
                print("ERROR with message")
                print(e)
                progress_label["text"] = "Failed due to {}".format(e)
            finally : 
                wb.Close(False)
                submit_btn["state"] = "normal"
                browse_btn["state"] = "normal"

        print("Total exec time : {}".format((time.time()-start_time)/60))
```

```
def file_submit_btn_click():
    if (file_name_appear_label["text"]==""):
        progress_label["text"] = "Please input your file"
    elif option_menu.get() == '':
        progress_label["text"] = "Please select 3pl name"
    else:
        try :
            submit_btn["state"] = "disabled"
            browse_btn["state"] = "disabled"
            progress_label["text"] = "Loading . . ."
            name3pl = option_menu.get()
            ingest = IngestGenerator(file_name,file_path,name3pl)
            print(get_file_name(file_name_appear_label["text"]))
            threading.Thread(target=ingest.generate_result_csv).start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error was raised when writing CSV with `polars` and `polars` has its own dependencies, when it's in exe form it needs to include --recursive-copy-metadata as per [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-recursive-copy-metadata) `pyinstaller --recursive-copy-metadata polars --onefile -w "myfile.py"`